# How to Convert URL Parameter to JSON (dict) in Python With Concise Codes

Tags: python

I have a URL with JSON encoded parameters:

```
http://host/endpoint?cart%5B4887%5D=3&cart%5B2576%5D=2&cart%5B2519%5D=4
```

After using `unquote(request.url)` (Flask), I got:

```
http://host/endpoint?cart[4887]=3&cart[2576]=2&cart[2519]=4
```

This URL comes from a .php function of WordPress plugin. The reason to use GET with URL parameters instead of POST is because I need to send data to an external API by my plugin without touching / modifying any existing files in WordPress. In the existing files in WordPress, the .php file has specified what wp endpoint to post in .

```
$cart_items_arr = array("4887"=>3, "2576"=>2, "2519"=4);
$url = add_query_arg( array("cart" => $cart_items_arr), URL);
```

The output that I want to extract from the URL is

```
{
  "4887": 3,
  "2576": 2,
  "2519": 4
}
```

What would be the neat and tidy way to convert a string to dictionary like this?

Comment: Those are not *JSON-encoded* parameters.

Comment: Where does your URL string comes from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use potentially use regex to get you most of the way:

```py
import re
str = 'http://host/endpoint?cart[4887]=3&cart[2576]=2&cart[2519]=4'
re.findall("\[(\d+)\]=(\d+)", str) # [('4887', '3'), ('2576', '2'), ('2519', '4')]
```

You should be able to easily map that into the dictionary you need.

Answer (score 1):

Looks `cart` is consistent, then you can just use a loop to strip them:

```
{k.strip('cart[]'): v for k, v in request.args.items()}
```